# Where I can find the list of popular hardware & software inventory systems?

Tags: inventory-software

I need to find applications to store inventory information about hardware & software that is running on it. I was trying to find such applications using google but without success.

Could you point me where I could find the list of such applications. I'm particularly interested in open source or very flexible apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is probably the closest you'll come to a list](http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?profile=all&platform=all&search=tag:network-inventory). I would recommend you look at [Lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/Download.aspx), alongside any others that you find. It comes in a free edition.

> ## Hardware inventory.
>
> Browse the web interface to see all hardware details of your scanned computers. Hardware change tracking will let you know when a component was replaced or removed.
>   Lansweeper scans over 60 different specifications of your computers.
>
> [image: Hardware]
>
> ## Software inventory.
>
> Browse the web interface to see all software installed on your computers.
>   Software can be approved for compliancy reasons and you can Google unknown software. If you want to digg deeper you can drill down on the software's publisher and version.
>
> [image: Software]

Answer (score 0):

We use Spiceworks, its not great, but seems to work okay. I know the MAP tool from Microsoft works okay too, but its really more for deployment planning, also free.

Answer (score -1):

lansweeper +1

10-strike network inventory (http://10-strike.com)

Trogon network inventory (http://trogonsoftware.com)

Total network inventory (softinventive)

emco software inventory (emcosoftware)

Comment: A list of links is not very helpful. Can you please explain what these programs do and how they can help so your answer is still useful if the links become dead? @ta.speot.is's answer is a good example.